# How to filter mongodb field from linked collection

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to know how can I propery filter field from another collection that is linked from main collection.

Here is my filter values

```
 if(!empty($filterDataBuyer['price'])){
    $findArray['price'] = intval($filterDataBuyer['price']);
  }
  if(!empty($filterDataBuyer['search'])){
    $findArray['full_name'] = $filterDataBuyer['search'];
  }
}

$findArray['type'] = 'buyer';
```

The `price` and `type` works fine but the `full_name` does not work

And here is for getting the data

```
$getData = [
      [
        '$match' => $findArray
      ],
      [
        '$project' => [
          '_id'            =>  ['$toString' => '$_id'],
          'type'          =>  '$type',
          'created_date'  =>  '$created_date',
          'offer_id'      =>  '$offer_id',
          'buyer_id'      =>  '$buyer_id',
          'traveler_id'   =>  '$raveler_id',
          'order_id'      =>  '$order_id',
          'price'         =>  '$price'
        ]
      ],

      [
        '$lookup' => [
          'from' => 'users',
          'let' => [
            'admin_id' =>  ['$toObjectId' => '$buyer_id'],
          ],
          'pipeline' => [
            [
              '$match' => [
                '$expr' => [
                  '$eq' => [
                    '$_id',
                    '$$admin_id'
                  ]
                ],
              ],
            ],
            [
              '$project' => [
                '_id'             =>  ['$toString' => '$_id'],
                'profile_image'   =>  '$profile_image',
                'full_name'       =>  '$full_name'
              ]
            ],

          ],
          'as' => 'profileData'
        ]
      ],
```

What I want to do is if `full_name` field is available, it could also filter the result by it, `price` and `type` can filter successfully but `full_name` is not. Result returns only if `full_name` has value on it.

My PHP version is `7.4.27` and mongodb extension is `1.12.0`

This is just two collections, `payment_details` and `users` where payment_details has `buyer_id` field that is reference to `users` `id` field

From mongocompass:

payment_details:
[image]

users:
[image]

Full Code update:

```
if(!empty($filterDataBuyer['price'])){
        /* FLIGHT-31 fix */
        $findArray['price'] = intval($filterDataBuyer['price']);
      }
      if(!empty($filterDataBuyer['search'])){
        $findArray['full_name'] = $filterDataBuyer['search'];
      }

$findArray['type'] = 'buyer';
    
    $buyer_trasections    =  $db->payment_details->find($findArray);
    $buyerRes_trasections =  iterator_to_array($buyer_trasections);

$getData = [
      [
        '$match' => $findArray
      ],
      [
        '$project' => [
          '_id'            =>  ['$toString' => '$_id'],
          'type'          =>  '$type',
          'created_date'  =>  '$created_date',
          'offer_id'      =>  '$offer_id',
          'buyer_id'      =>  '$buyer_id',
          'traveler_id'   =>  '$raveler_id',
          'order_id'      =>  '$order_id',
          'price'         =>  '$price'
        ]
      ],

      [
        '$lookup' => [
          'from' => 'users',
          'let' => [
            'admin_id' =>  ['$toObjectId' => '$buyer_id'],
          ],
          'pipeline' => [
            [
              '$match' => [
                '$expr' => [
                  '$eq' => [
                    '$_id',
                    '$$admin_id'
                  ]
                ],
              ],
            ],
            [
              '$project' => [
                '_id'             =>  ['$toString' => '$_id'],
                'profile_image'   =>  '$profile_image',
                'full_name'       =>  '$full_name'
              ]
            ],

          ],
          'as' => 'profileData'
        ]
      ],

      [
        '$skip' =>  $page
      ],
      [
        '$limit' =>  $config['per_page'], 
      ],
      [
        '$sort' => [ 'created_date'=> -1]
      ]
    ];
    $buyer_trasec     =  $db->payment_details->aggregate($getData);
    $buyerRes_trasec  =  iterator_to_array($buyer_trasec);

    echo "<pre>";print_r($buyerRes_trasec);exit;
```

And this is the sample, first result for echo "`<pre>";print_r($buyerRes_trasec);exit;`

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your data and reproducible scenario. Better a mongo playground online.

Comment: Will the documents have a full_name field at the time the $match stage runs?

Comment: Hi Sir @Gibbs, already updated the thread. sorry i am not familiar with mongo playground online. this is my first mongo db project from other developer..thank you

Comment: Hi Sir @Joe, already updated my question. thank you!

Comment: Full name field is empty in the attached image. Is it the reason?

Comment: Are you expecting case insensitive searches on full name?

Comment: @Gibbs i haven't tried that case sensitive or not, tried to search exact word but nothing found